# Using grep -f and -w together

Tags: unix, grep, pattern-matching

I have two files like this:

abc.txt

```
a  
b   
z   
1  
10
```

and abcd.txt

```
a  
b  
c  
d  
1  
10  
100  
1000
```

I would like:

```
a  
b  
1  
10
```

I would like to use `grep -fw abc.txt abcd.txt` to search through every line of abc.txt and print lines which match the entire word. If I just use `grep -f`, I get lines 100 since the pattern '10' matches '100'. But `grep -f -w abc.txt abcd.txt` produces:

```
a  
b  
1
```

and doesn't print out the 10. So, I guess, what is the best way to match every line in abc.txt with the entire line of abcd.txt ?

Comment: Do you have whitespace at the end of some lines?

Comment: Anyway, how about `comm -12 <(sort test.in) <(sort test.2)`

Comment: Yes, there is a newline character at the end of every line. So, its Pattern\n